# mod_wsgi-express rewrite-rules causing loss of CSS/JS files and browser crashes

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have a Flask/Angular app that I'm serving with this command.  Flask, Angular, and mod_wsgi-express are all mandatory components for this project.

```
$ mod_wsgi-express start-server run_apache_server.wsgi --rewrite-rules rewrite_psyche_data.conf
```

`run_apache_server.wsgi` looks like this (`psyche_data_master` is the git repo and `psyche_data` is the python module for the flask app):

```
# run_apache_server.wsgi

import sys

#Expand Python classes path with your app's path
sys.path.insert(0, "/Users/Jakob/Desktop/dev_projects/psyche_data_master/psyche_data")
from psyche_data import app

#Initialize WSGI app object
application = app
```

I've tried a few things here based on help forums in getting the 404 errors fixed (These are caused by angular route issues when using this HTML option that I must use.)

1) When `rewrite_psyche_data.conf` looks like this:

```
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]
```

... I end up with my pages looking like raw HTML and I see console errors saying "unexpected token: <" and when I click on the errors, the JS files themselves are filled with HTML.

--------------------->8--------------------

2) When `rewrite_psyche_data.conf` looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

...I get a 404 error on the index page itself at the root URL (localhost:8000)
The command doesn't seem to fail when I run it:

```
$ mod_wsgi-express start-server run_apache_server.wsgi --rewrite-rules rewri_psyche_data.conf 
Server URL         : http://localhost:8000/
Server Root        : /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:503
Server Conf        : /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:503/httpd.conf
Error Log File     : /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:503/error_log (warn)
Rewrite Rules      : /Users/Jakob/Desktop/dev_projects/psyche_data_master/rewrite_psyche_data.conf
Request Capacity   : 5 (1 process * 5 threads)
Request Timeout    : 60 (seconds)
Startup Timeout    : 15 (seconds)
Queue Backlog      : 100 (connections)
Queue Timeout      : 45 (seconds)
Server Capacity    : 20 (event/worker), 20 (prefork)
Server Backlog     : 500 (connections)
Locale Setting     : en_US.UTF-8
```

...and these two lines show in the error log file:

```
[Mon May 22 21:17:00.788635 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 12005:tid 140735965213632] AH00489: Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) mod_wsgi/4.5.15 Python/2.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon May 22 21:17:00.789013 2017] [core:notice] [pid 12005:tid 140735965213632] AH00094: Command line: 'httpd (mod_wsgi-express)  -f /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:503/httpd.conf -D MOD_WSGI_MPM_ENABLE_EVENT_MODULE -D MOD_WSGI_MPM_EXISTS_EVENT_MODULE -D MOD_WSGI_MPM_EXISTS_WORKER_MODULE -D MOD_WSGI_MPM_EXISTS_PREFORK_MODULE -D FOREGROUND'
```

--------------------->8--------------------

3) When I run this, the app works, but I get 404 errors any time I refresh any of the URLs generated by Angular Routing:

```
$ mod_wsgi-express start-server run_apache_server.wsgi
```

Should I be doing something other that `--rewrite-rules` like `--include-file`?

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging on the flask side and doing this seems to have fixed the issue for now:

```
# routing for basic pages (pass routing onto the Angular app)
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/about')
@app.route('/contact')
@app.route('/studies')
def basic_pages(**kwargs):
    return make_response(open('psyche_data/templates/index.html').read())
```

Now when I load the route called "/about", etc. the URL changes, I can refresh it, and there is no 404 error. Even without the rewrite rules.

Comment: You shouldn't have needed the rewrite rules if you put the static files in the directory used for static files by mod_wsgi-express as it has those rewrite rules by default in the configuration it generates. If you already had static files in a directory somewhere, you would use the ``--document-root`` option to simply specify where they were.

Comment: I think `--document-root` is made useless by my use of `sys.path.insert` which points to the project root

Comment: The ``--document-root`` has got nothing to do with your Python code. It is the directory containing static files. The initial rewrite rules you mentioned are by default already used by ``mod_wsgi-express``. What the rules do is that if a URL matches a static file in the directory (as specified by ``--document-root``), the static file will be served up. If the URL doesn't match a static file, then the request will be passed through to the Python WSGI application instead to handle.

Comment: So if you aren't putting your static files in a directory for ``mod_wsgi-express`` to handle, there was never a need for those rewrite rules in the first place and your issues were all to do with your Flask application routes.